# VBA Architecture Tips - Macro packaging

Tags: excel, vba, module

I hacked together a proof of concept for Excel to get data from a database and need to package this so that it can be distributed to our customers.  My first attempt was just to throw all my code into a code module, but then in Excel I can see all the modules in the macro list, when I really only want the main one in the list.  I'm guessing that I need to move the subroutines that are not to be run directly into class modules so that they're hidden.  Are there any other tips on how to package the macro code so it's simpler and safer to give to customers?

Comment: If your macro is accessing a database, don't forget to password-protect the VB Project.  If any of the information in the macro is particularly sensitive, then be aware that the this password protection isn't very robust (at most it will block the idly curious).  In that case you'd want some type of compliled add-in.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not a Sub is hidden in the macro list is based on it's scope (e.g. public, private).  If you make a Sub private, it will not be listed in the Macros list.

```
'This sub is public
Public Sub myPublicSub()
    MsgBox "hello world"
End Sub

'This sub is also public
Sub mySub()
    MsgBox "hello world"
End Sub

'This sub is private
Private Sub myPrivateSub()
    MsgBox "hello world"
End Sub
```

Class modules are used to create classes, which are likely not useful or necessary for your solution (if the code operates the way you want it to now).

If this is for a customer I would strongly recommend packaging as a .xlam (Excel 2007+ Add-In) and learning how to customize the Ribbon to include a button for your macros.  The macro list is not particularly usable.  (see http://openxmldeveloper.org/archive/2006/05/25/CustomUIeditor.aspx for a free ribbon xml editor "Attachment(s)" at bottom of article.  see http://www.rondebruin.nl/ribbon.htm for some tutorials)

For protecting your code from being viewed/stolen, the VBA project can be password protected, but this should not be considered rock solid protection.