# create a button on worksheet to run vba code

Tags: excel, vba

Okay this question is going to show just how basic my knowledge is :(

My other question was answered perfectly and i now have a Code that runs moving a line of text to another workbook.

Currently I run this by pressing alt F11 and then the green play button. I have tried to add a button to the file so its easier for others and followed these instructions:

Go to the Developer tab in the ribbon.
Select the Button Form Control from the menu.
Right click and hold the mouse then drag and release to create your button.
The Assign Macro window will pop up and you can select the VBA procedure you want to run from the button.
Press the OK button.

It works to a degree, I can add the button and get the the assign macro pop up but then my VBA procedure is not showing - what am I doing wrong please? I think its something to do with naming the VBA maybe?

Comment: May your sub is private. Make it public. Public keyword infront of sub name will make sub public like `Public Sub MySub()`. Write your sub in standard module.

Comment: see this post [VBA Architecture Tips - Macro packaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236814/vba-architecture-tips-macro-packaging/5236896#5236896)

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is going into the developer panel,
click on Insert, button ActiveX
then right click > Visualize Code
and paste your code here

Tell me if it works